# What is an adjective for "requires a lot of work"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

For example, 
Starting a new business requires a lot of work.

What would be an adjective in: Starting a new business is *_*.

Comment: You could say *time-consuming* but I think something such as *a major commitment* fits better. The perfect adjective isn't always available.

Comment: _Hectic_ might fit well.

Comment: *Taxing, arduous, demanding, laborious, onerous,...* This is Too Broad *and* POB

Comment: as a German native speaker, I often look for a "is" phrase like yours (because we use such phrases a lot in German). But I have come to learn that looking for an "is"-equivalent in English might often not be the best fit. Does it have to be a is-phrase? Why not just "requires a lot of work" like in your first sentence? (BTW @Ben I was not referring to your comment. Just noticed that you mention "German" and so do I - it's a coincidence)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider *[challenging](https://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/challenging)*

> Calling for full use of one's abilities or resources in a difficult but stimulating effort [*American Heritage Dictionary*]

Alternatives are *burdensome, onerous*, and *arduous*, but all of those have somewhat negative tones.

Answer (score 9):

[*laborsome*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/laborsome?s=ts)

> 1.) Made with, or requiring, great labor, pains, or diligence.

[*toilsome*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/toilsome?s=t)

> "Characterized by or involving toil; laborious or fatiguing."

[*exhaustive*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exhaustive?s=ts)

> 2.) tending to exhaust or drain, as resources or strength: a protracted, exhaustive siege of illness.

[*strenuous*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/strenuous?s=ts)

> 1.) characterized by vigorous exertion, as action, efforts, life, etc.: a strenuous afternoon of hunting.
>
> 2.) demanding or requiring vigorous exertion; laborious: To think deeply is a strenuous task.
>
> 3.) vigorous, energetic, or zealously active: a strenuous person; a strenuous intellect.

Also:

- *labor intensive* (already mentioned below)
- *a chore*
- *requires perseverance*
- *requires persistence*
- *requires dedication*
- *requires exertion*

Answer (score 4):

If you want a single word for "a lot of work", consider "*onerous*" or "*laborious*", though I'm not sure "a lot of work" captures all the relevant obstacles to starting a business.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:  *labor-intensive*.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of relationships, the word for “requires a lot of work” is *[needy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/needy#Adjective)*, meaning  “Desiring constant affirmation, lacking in self confidence”.  Wiktionary gives  the following example sentence:

> It's emotionally exhausting to be around her because she's so **needy**.

Answer (score 1):

*Gruelling* comes to mind. It is defined as “extremely tiring and demanding”.